# Медленный sendmail в ubuntu

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu, sendmail

Здравствуйте, в чем может быть проблема, установил на сервер nginx + php-fpm, к нему установил sendmail, сайт работает быстро, но как нужно отправить письмо - шлет его долго, минуту целую.

```
QUEUE_MODE="${DAEMON_MODE}";
в файле:
/etc/mail/sendmail.conf
```

Comment: В `/etc/hosts` есть строка `127.0.0.1 мой-домен.рф`?

Comment: да строка такая есть

Comment: может в логи посмотреть? может коннект до самого почтового сервера плохой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что не настроен hostname, добавил в хост

```
127.0.1.1   mail.site.loc dogmar
```

и все заработало